# Rank of the difference between two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let Matrix $B_{N \times N}=I_{N \times N}-\frac{1}{N}A_{N \times N}$, where $I_{N \times N}$ is the identity matrix and all the elements in $A_{N \times N}$ equal to one. What is the rank of the matrix $B$?

Of course the rank of $I_{N \times N}$ is $N$ and the rank of $A$ is $1$. I tried to find the rank using matlab for different values of $N$ and always the rank is $N-1$, but I can't prove it mathematically. Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the rank of $B = I - uu^T/n$  where $u = (1,1,1,\cdots, 1)^T$ is $n- 1.$
here is the reason:  the eigenvalues of $uu^T/n$ are $1,0,0,\cdots, 0.$ and the eigenvalues of $B$ are $0, 1,1, \cdots, 1.$

Comment: No, the eigenvalues of B are either $0$ or $1$ since it is an idempotent matrix, I also checked with matlab.

Comment: @Alammouri, you are right. all the $-1$'s must be $1$s. i fixed it.